# multiple sum using join in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is Rudresh BR, Trying to obtain data of same rows into multiple columns also by doing sum. But stuck with an issue, Please find the below mentioned details regarding the issue,

Expected Data:

[image: Expected Data]

But obtained Data:

[image: But obtained Data]

Data Existing in Table

1. List item

[image: Actual Data in Table]

Query used:

```
select 
    a.BM_BANK_NAME,
    SUM(PCBunit.BID_CURRENCY_VALUE) as PCBUnitSum,
     SUM(PTBunit.BID_CURRENCY_VALUE) as PTBUnitSum  
from 
     dbo.BG_Mtr_Bank_Master a 
     inner join dbo.BG_Tra_Issuance_Details PCBunit on a.BM_ID=PCBunit.BID_BANK_NAME and PCBunit.BID_UNIT_DIVISION='PCB' 
     inner join dbo.BG_Tra_Issuance_Details PTBunit on a.BM_ID=PTBunit.BID_BANK_NAME and PTBunit.BID_UNIT_DIVISION='PTB' 
group by 
     a.BM_BANK_NAME,
     PCBunit.BID_UNIT_DIVISION,
     PTBunit.BID_UNIT_DIVISION
```

PCBUnitSum and PTBUnitSum is the sum of rows of BID_Currency_Value of PCB and PTB respectively.

What I am observing is once the sum is done i.e 3000(which i am expecting as output) , it's redoing the sum based on number of rows PCB and PTB exists respectively, so as there are 3 rows of PCB, 3000+3000+3000=9000 is given as O/P.

I request everyone to,
Please help me out to find what's going wrong?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL?  These are different products that, often, require different solutions.  Please don't double tag.

Answer (score 2):

Do not self-join the table, use case

```
select a.BM_BANK_NAME
     , SUM(case when t.BID_UNIT_DIVISION ='PCB' then t.BID_CURRENCY_VALUE end) as PCBUnitSum
     , SUM(case when t.BID_UNIT_DIVISION ='PTB' then t.BID_CURRENCY_VALUE end) as PTBUnitSum  
  from dbo.BG_Mtr_Bank_Master a 
 inner 
  join dbo.BG_Tra_Issuance_Details t 
    on a.BM_ID = t.BID_BANK_NAME 
   and t.BID_UNIT_DIVISION in ('PCB', 'PTB')
 group  
    by a.BM_BANK_NAME
```

Comment: It will throw error cause of line `and t.BID_UNIT_DIVISION = in ('PCB', 'PTB')`

Comment: Rahul , I am going to select Distinct values from table. Thanks to you too :)

Comment: Please consider [accepting this answer].  Accepting answers regards the contributor and helps others, with similar problems, to find a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @list_item TABLE ( unit NVARCHAR(5),bank NVARCHAR(5),curr INT)
INSERT INTO @list_item VALUES ('PCB','SBI',1000),('PCB','SBI',1000),
('PCB','SBI',1000),('PTB','SBI',1000),('PTB','SBI',1000),
('PTB','SBI',1000)

SELECT bank,
SUM(CASE WHEN unit='PCB' THEN curr END) PCBUnitSum,
SUM(CASE WHEN unit='PTB' THEN curr END) PTBUnitSum
FROM ( SELECT unit,bank,SUM(curr)curr FROM @list_item 
group by unit,bank ) A GROUP BY bank
```

This might help. :)